# Отладчик Android Studio игнорирует точки останова внутри Catch блока

Tags: android-studio, отладка

Есть такой блок кода:

```
try {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();               // здесь не останавливается
    Log.d("log_tag",e.getMessage());   // здесь не останавливается
    return false;                      // останавливается только здесь
}
```

При выбросе исключения, не происходит остановки в первых двух строчках блока Catch, может так и должно быть?

При этом в логе по тегу "log_tag" ничего нет.

Если избавиться от Try/Catch блока, и оставить только:

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

то перед выполнением второй строки оба выражения по отдельности рассчитываются как TRUE. Но во время исполнения строка возвращает FALSE. При этом, отслеживаемые значения для

```
networkInfo != null
```

и

```
networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
```

с этого момента показывают не TRUE, а

```
Cannot find local variable 'networkInfo'
```

Comment: А может catch не срабатывает?) Вы скажете, тогда странно, что останавливается на return false, который вроде бы внутри catch, но компиляция штука такая... В прошлом мне доводилось копать dex байт-код довольно много.

Comment: Но ведь на следующем шаге, false действительно возвращается туда, куда должен. Значит цепочка работает. Я не понимаю как может сработать return false если не сработал catch блок. Если такое возможно, то лучше бросить изучение Android прямо сейчас ))

Comment: Боюсь, впечатлительным под Windows Phone писать придется.

Comment: вы пишите код не на андроиде, а на java.

Comment: Предмет, который я изучаю называется Android Programming, то что при этом используется Java я в курсе. А вот как выловить ошибку пока так и не ясно.

Comment: я к тому, что такой код на Java под любой ОС будет вести себя одинаково, и "бросание" в этой связи имено ОС Android несколько поспешное решение. Нужно как то различать язык программирования и  операционную систему, в которой он выполняется. К тому же ваша проблема не с обработкой исключения, как выяснилось, а с выполнение условия

Comment: Какие оба выражения по отдельности возвращают true? Иными словами, почему вы уверены, что ``return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();`` даст вам true и что вы вообще хотите выловить этим блоком try-catch?

Comment: Выходит что Try/Catch блок действительно не срабатывал. Я попробовал  поставил в конец Catch блока return true вместо return false, но с удивлением обнаружил что возвращается всё равно FALSE, хотя отладчик вроде как останавливается внутри Catch блока и затем следует выполнение return true. Smlnc был прав.

Comment: При остановке на первой строке (когда не использую Try/Catch), беру networkInfo != null и вбиваю в watch list, показывает TRUE, то же самое показывает для networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting(). Это всё код из Lynda курса, сам не знаю зачем здесь Try/Catch.

Comment: исполнение кода процессором - штука, полностью исключающая какую либо магию, зато никак не защищенная от человеческого фактора. То есть, если возвращает false, значит выражение абсолютно точно равно false, но в ваши предположения почему то обратные. выведите 3 условия в код по отдельности, ставьте точки останова и возвращайте через return значение, а не выражение, это позволит понять, где проблема

Comment: networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() до выполнения строки рассчитывается как TRUE, а при выполнении -     Cannot find local variable 'networkInfo'.

Comment: видимо по вашей новой проблеме нужно задать новый вопрос, так как на этот уже получен ответ и проблема первоначального вопроса решена. ответы на новую проблему будут не соответствать первоначальной проблеме

Comment: Хотелось бы всё-таки узнать, почему отладчик прыгает в Catch если он не сработал. Ну да ладно, будем знать, что так бывает.

Answer (score 2):

Проверив код в голове, я пришел к выводу, что все работает правильно. До catch дело не доходит, потому что причин для этого нет:

- функция `conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();` выполняется без ошибок.
- функция `networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();` выполняется без ошибок.

Исключение для catch может случиться только в этих двух местах. А так как все нормально, то дело переходит к

```
return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

А уж почему там на выходе `false` нужно смотреть отдельно.

Comment: Косяк с возвратом false, происходит только в режиме отладки. В нормальном режиме возвращает true как надо.